# huggingface classification struggling with prediction

Tags: python, nlp, classification, huggingface-transformers

I am fine tuning longformer and then making prediction using `TextClassificationPipeline` and `model(**inputs)` methods. I am not sure why I get different results

```
import pandas as pd
import datasets
from transformers import LongformerTokenizerFast, LongformerForSequenceClassification, Trainer, TrainingArguments, LongformerConfig
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader#Dataset, 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_recall_fscore_support
from tqdm import tqdm
#import wandb
import os
from datasets import Dataset
from transformers import TextClassificationPipeline, AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification

tokenizer = LongformerTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('folder_path/', max_length = maximum_len)
```

Loading the fine tuned model from a saved location. Using original tokenizer

```
saved_location='c:/xyz'
model_saved=AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(saved_location)
pipe = TextClassificationPipeline(model=model_saved, tokenizer=tokenizer, device=0)#tokenizer_saved, padding=True, truncation=True)
prediction = pipe(["The text to predict"], return_all_scores=True)
prediction
[[{'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.7107483148574829},
  {'label': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.2892516553401947}]]
```

2nd method

```
inputs = tokenizer("The text to predict", return_tensors="pt").to(device)
outputs = model_saved(**inputs)#, labels=labels)
print (outputs['logits'])
#tensor([[ 0.4552, -0.4438]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
torch.sigmoid(outputs['logits'])
#tensor([[0.6119, 0.3908]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)
```

`AutoModelForSequenceClassification` returns probabilities `0.71 and 0.29`. When I look at the 2nd method. It returns logits  `0.4552, -0.4438` which convert to probabilities `0.6119, 0.3908`

***#update 1***

The first link [TextClassificationPipeline](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.17.0/en/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TextClassificationPipeline) from cronoik's answer says below

```
function_to_apply (str, optional, defaults to "default") — The function to apply to the model outputs in order to retrieve the scores. Accepts four different values:
"default": if the model has a single label, will apply the sigmoid function on the output. If the model has several labels, will apply the softmax function on the output.
"sigmoid": Applies the sigmoid function on the output.
"softmax": Applies the softmax function on the output.
"none": Does not apply any function on the output.
```

as this is a binary classification problem (single label) shouldn't it apply sigmoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `model.config.num_labels==2`, if that is the case, the [TextClassificationPipeline](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.17.0/en/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TextClassificationPipeline) applies softmax and not sigmoid to calculate the probabilities ([code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/198c335d219a5eb4d3f124fdd1ce1a9cd9f78a9b/src/transformers/pipelines/text_classification.py#L142)).

```py
import torch

logits = torch.tensor([ 0.4552, -0.4438])
print(torch.softmax(logits,0))
```

Output:

```
tensor([0.7107, 0.2893])
```

Comment: Please reply update 1

Comment: @user2543622 as I said, I think you have trained your model with two labels (e.g. positive and negative instead of positive or not). Please check `model.config.num_labels`. If that is the case, the error is not in the pipeline but in how you have trained your model.

Comment: thanks for the help, could you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71768061/huggingface-transformers-classification-using-num-labels-1-vs-2