# huggingface transformers classification using num_labels 1 vs 2

Tags: python, classification, huggingface-transformers

question 1)

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71755535/huggingface-classification-struggling-with-prediction) suggested that for a binary classification problem I could use `num_labels` as 1 (positive or not) or 2 (positive and negative). Is there any guideline regarding which setting is better? It seems that if we use 1 then probability would be calculated using `sigmoid` function and if we use 2 then probabilities would be calculated using `softmax` function.

question 2)

In both cases are my y labels going to be same? each data point will have 0 or 1 and not one hot encoding? For example, if I have 2 data points then y would be `0,1` and not `[0,0],[0,1]`

I have very unbalanced classification problem where class 1 is present only 2% of times. In my training data I am oversampling

question 3)

My data is in `pandas dataframe` and I am converting it to a `dataset` and creating y variable using below. How should I cast my y column - `label` if I am planning to use `num_labels`=1?

```
`train_dataset=Dataset.from_pandas(train_df).cast_column("label", ClassLabel(num_classes=2, names=['neg', 'pos'], names_file=None, id=None))`
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it probably is kind of late. But I want to point out one thing, according to the Hugging Face code, if you set num_labels = 1, it will actually trigger the regression modeling, and the loss function will be set to MSELoss(). You can find the code [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/7ae6f070044b0171a71f3269613bf02fd9fca6f2/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L1564-L1575).

Also, in their own tutorial, for a binary classification problem (IMDB, positive vs. negative), they set num_labels = 2.

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, TrainingArguments, Trainer
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased", num_labels=2)
```

Here is the [link](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/sequence_classification).

Answer (score 4):

1. As answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207049/neural-network-for-binary-classification-use-1-or-2-output-neurons), the *Sigmoid* activation function is just a special case of 2-class *Softmax* activation function. With some weights set to zero, the second output is always zero. Thus **for performance reasons** like updating faster and having fewer parameters, you should use **sigmoid**.
2. When your output dimension is one, one-hot encoding means assigning 0 to one class and 1 to the other. So for 2 data points, your y would be `0,1`.
3. [`ClassLabel`](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.0.0/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.ClassLabel) is used to give names to integer labels that represent classes. So to use that, your `y` column should consist of zeros and ones. You can see in the example below that the `ClassLabel` column with two values is represented with one column consisting of `0` and `1`.

`PyTorch` example:

```py
from datasets import Dataset,ClassLabel
import pandas as pd
import torch

train_df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[1,2,3,4,5],'label':[0,1,0,1,0]})
train_dataset=Dataset.from_pandas(train_df).cast_column("label", ClassLabel(num_classes=2, names=['neg', 'pos']))
train_dataset.set_format(type='torch', columns=['column', 'label'])
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=5)
print(next(iter(dataloader)))
```

output:

```
{'column': tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 'label': tensor([0, 1, 0, 1, 0])}
```

- If your `y` column consists of `neg` and `pos` values, pandas would do the job as below:

```py
label_mapping = {'neg':0,'pos':1}
train_df['label'] = train_df['label'].apply(lambda x:label_mapping['x'])
```

Comment: thanks. But I dont think that your answer is specific to `huggingface transformers` libary. Correct me if you have tested your approach on the `huggingface transformers` libary

Comment: I appreicate your help. I am still not clear. How would you change this line `train_dataset=Dataset.from_pandas(train_df).cast_column("label", ClassLabel(num_classes=2, names=['neg', 'pos']))
` to indicate `num_classes=1`?

Comment: you don't need to change `num_classes`, cause you actually have 2 classes (`neg` and `pos`). but the point is, the `datasets` library one-hot encodes any `ClassLabel` column with 2 classes into a one-dimensional vector. in general, you can one-hot encode any column with `n` different labels using `n-1`-dimensional vectors.